# Pandas: passing mulitiple column when selecting data

Tags: python, pandas

I can do `pd_data = pd_data[pd_data['db_rating']>0]`, to filter the data, selecting records with `db_rating > 0`.

Now I want to involve other columns as well, for example, selecting both `db_rating>0` and `imdb_ratings_count>1000` the same time.

But 
`pd_data = pd_data[pd_data['db_rating']>0 and pd_data['imdb_ratings_count']>1000]` gives me error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-f83883d4bac8> in <module>()
      3 pd_data['imdb_rating'] = pd_data['imdb_rating'].astype(float)
      4 pd_data['imdb_ratings_count'] = pd_data['imdb_ratings_count'].astype(float)
----> 5 pd_data = pd_data[pd_data['db_rating']>0 and pd_data['imdb_ratings_count']>1000]
      6 pd_data.describe()

D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    696         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    697                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 698                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    699 
    700     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is overwriting the boolean `&` operator for this. This should work:

```
pd_data = pd_data[(pd_data['db_rating']>0) & (pd_data['imdb_ratings_count']>1000)]
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 2):

Use bitwise operators when working with boolean vectors in pandas:

```
pd_data = pd_data[(pd_data['db_rating']>0) & (pd_data['imdb_ratings_count']>1000)]
```

Comment: OMG, I tried `&&` and `and`, but just didn't try his.